# Everything inside form input is either overlapping or not showing

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, position

I was making a login form with animations. If there is only one input field, it works perfect but when I add other input fields, they overlap with each other and the animations don't work properly. The submit button and checkbox gets hidden.

```
<div class="form">
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name" placeholder=" " required>
            <label for="name" class="label-name">
                <span class="content-name">username</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="name" placeholder=" " required>
            <label for="name" class="label-name">
                <span class="content-name">password</span>
            </label>
            <div class="hide">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
            </div>
            <button>Login</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2dteaz0/1/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning require to use a relative positioning on a parent element.

```
.inputs > div {
  position: relative;
}
.inputs input[type="text"], .inputs input[type="password"]{
  ...
```

[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/s1Lf24th/1/)

*edit 1* CSS rules for specified input type only

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really helped!! I just wanted to ask that why is it not showing the checkbox? Any ideas?

Comment: @AyushShah I updated my answer to include `.inputs input[type="text"], .inputs input[type="password"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

Change the following CSS property as this;

```
.form{
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not working. The above answer worked